# Area under curve bounded by rectangles

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it possible to find the common area between curve $xy>b^2$ (rectangular hyperbola) and the rectangle $2\leq x\leq A$ and $2\leq y\leq B$ where $A$ and $B$ are much larger than $b^2$?

From what I think, it should be something like area of rectangle subtracted the area of hyperbola with x-axis. But doing this we also remove the area that is not in the rectangle(for some values of $b^2$), so we add that small part again.

However, how to calculate the area between the hyperbola and x-axis. If I integrate the hyperbola from $2\leq x\leq A$ what about the bound on $y$, how to consider both the bounds?

I don't know if it's really the right approach, but it should not be undefined because $x$ and $y$ are bounded. So how do I calculate the area?

Comment: What do you mean by $x*y$?

Comment: @Allawonder I mean $x$ multiplied by $y$

Comment: I see. Shouldn't that be better written as $xy$? Also, the inequality $xy>b^2$ defines a region bounded by a hyperbola, not a hyperbola.

Comment: @Allawonder I am sorry, I couldn't really understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that $xy>b^2$ is not a hyperbola, but a region whose boundary is a hyperbola. Is this clearer?

Comment: @Allawonder Oh yes I understand that, I just kind of mentioned it to make the question clearer actually. :P

Comment: Calling something by a different name doesn't make it clearer -- it obscures the point.

Comment: @Allawonder, allow me to make a comment which here is not important but in general -- I feel -- it is. For long years I insist, but nobody else seems to care, that all operation symbols should be written explicitly. For instance, a product $\ s\cdot i\cdot n\ $ should not be written as $\ sin.\ $ We should see **immediately, at one glance**, that we have a product and not the sinus function. Today's mathematics is so rich that my convection is essential. On the other hand, most of the time we do not need commas as for ordered pairs, $\ (a\ b)\ $ -- a comma is just an eyesore.

Comment: @WlodAA I don't think anyone would want to multiply such a combination of letters, because of possible confusion. In any case since multiplication is commutative, if you must use those letters together, you could write the product as $isn$ or some other permutation. Also, the comma helps distinguish components of a *row* vector. Even if your arguments were valid, OP should have written $x\times y.$

Comment: @Allawonder, nobody should waste time and energy on superficial permutations which may even break some natural order. Also, multiplication doesn't have to be commutative. It's especially awkward these days when function/categorical composition is mixed with multiplication. It's crucial to wrote $\ f\circ g$ while on other occasions $ f\cdot g$. Obviously, notation $\ f^n\ $ is no good. It should be $\ \prod^n\! f\ $ for product, and $\ \bigcirc ^n\! f\ $ for composition. There is more to it. (And of course, $\ times\ $ these days stands for the cartesian product).

Comment: People react with a knee jerk but long years ago I've spent time on notation. Mathematical notation follows its traditions often by inertia. It's hard to improve things (as your, @Allawonder, reaction proves).

Comment: @WlodAA Oh, I see. A freak. Have a nice day!

Comment: @WlodAA I'm happy to be ugly by the definition of someone like you. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that $\ b>0\ $ (why not?! :-)

Then, the only non-trivial case is $\ b>2;\ $
thus let's assume this $\ b>2.$

Now let's solve the problem, i.e. let's do the computation.

Let
$$\ \alpha:=\frac Ab\qquad \beta:=\frac Bb
    \qquad d:=\frac 2b $$

The common area between curve $x*y>1$ (rectangular hyperbola) and the rectangle $\ d\leq x\leq \alpha\ $ and $d\leq y\leq \beta\ $ is

$$ (\alpha-d)\cdot(\beta-d) - \int_d^\frac 1d
\frac 1x\cdot dx\quad =\\ \ \\
\ (\alpha-d)\cdot(\beta-d)\ +\ 2\cdot \log(d) $$

(of course $\ \log(d)<0\ $ since $\ 0<d<1$).

Now, the original area is the above times $\ b^2,$
i.e.

$$ (A-2)\cdot(B-2)\ +\ 2\cdot(\log(2)-\log(b)) $$

*I think that that's it.*

> ### ---------

**PS.** You may consider $\ 2\ $ as an arbitrary positive real parameter,
just imagine that it is arbitrary $\ z>0.\ $ The result will hold
under this general notation. (If you squeeze your eyes then you'll
see "$z$" in place of $2$ :-).

Comment: By interesting, I mean it's interesting that you solved it in a manner I didn't approach it, and I thanked you because rather than posting a hint or a half thought answer, you tried to make it a complete answer. I am sorry, I never meant to disrespect you.

Comment: @resound "I never meant to disrespect you.". Well, you've succeeded. Even now, you've written that I "tried". I didn't try. I simply have provided an answer. You may simply **acknowledge the correctness of my solution** or you may **invalidate** it if I were wrong. (And one may also ask straightforward questions, of course). That's all.

Comment: @resound, you have asked about the area (remember?) and not about the integer points. These questions are related though, and this relationship forms a classical research topic.